# Site-to-site VPN connection between VMs in a private network and remote Linux hosts

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-networking, virtualbox, site-to-site-vpn

Recently I've faced with a problem - connect multiple VMs running on bare metal servers with Linux hosts in the remote location via the Internet.

Basically, what I need is a simple VPN setup where I will be able to spin up VirtualBox machines on the server in the private network with predefined local IP addresses and be able to get access to the same network from the laptop in the remote location.

I wanna be able to add additional desktops in the remote locations to this network via the Internet so VMs with local IPs will be available to them.

That's how the current setup looks like (simplified):
[image: current setup]
And that's what I want:
[image: setup with vpn]

I'm looking for open-source software or SaaS to implement this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using ZeroTier for this purpose:
https://www.zerotier.com

It will do what you want within reason, and it is likely free for the environment you've described.